# While calling post api with a large data of images i am getting 524 error

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, server

I am using Laravel as my backend and React JS as front-end. I have an image upload functionality which was working perfectly earlier. The client upgraded the server. Now while uploading fewer images (3-4) it is working fine but while uploading 20-30 images I get a response of 524.
I am thinking the api is not even getting called at all because i cannot see the payload and even if I write return on the first line of the api code(backend laravel) to exit the code immediately I am still getting the error after 1.9 Mins.I can see the payload before the api call is successful in all other cases.I am not sure but i think cloudflare is integrated in the server.I am just a Full Stack developer.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

I tried increasing the server timeout and max upload size too.

Comment: I would suggest breaking the files down into smaller batches. you say 1.9 minutes, are you using Cloudflare?

Comment: 524 error code, it seems like Cloudflare error `A timeout occurred`. 
Do you need to upload all files to the server? If u use s3 or Google Cloud Storage - I suggest the Signed URL functionality.

Comment: don't try to upload large data sets in one go, split them into chunks instead. Or in your case make each image upload separately, assuming one image by itself is not too big.

Comment: Yes i am using cloudfare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the server restrictions..contacting the support team resolved my issue.